# Defining foldl in terms of foldr in Standard ML

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, sml, fold

The defined code is

```
fun foldl f e l = let
    fun g(x, f'') = fn y => f''(f(x, y)) 
    in foldr g (fn x => x) l e end
```

I don't understand how this works; 
what is the purpose of `g(x, f'')`?

I also find a similar example in Haskell,
the definition is quite short

```
myFoldl f z xs = foldr step id xs z
    where
        step x g a = g (f a x)
```

Comment: The `fun` keyword in ocaml is used to create an anonymous function. Did you mean `let rec foldl f e l = ...`?

Comment: This is a classic exercise, sometimes jokingly referred to as "buscar el levante por el poniente" ;-)

Comment: @chi I missed the joke. Mind explaining?

Comment: Just realized that the OP's OCaml code is actually SML code.

Comment: @AaditMShah You fold _right_ to obtain a fold _left_, similarly to going west to reach the east.

Comment: @chi According to [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/#auto/en/buscar%20el%20levante%20por%20el%20poniente) "buscar el levante por el poniente" means "seek the release by the setting" in Spanish.

Comment: @AaditMShah That is the motto attributed to Columbus: it roughly means "to seek the East by way of the West" -- he expected to reach India (the East) by circumnavigating the globe going westwards.

Answer (score 7):

Let's dissect the Haskell implementation of `myFoldl` and then take a look at the <strike>ocaml</strike> SML code. First, we'll look at some type signatures:

```hs
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -- the step function
      -> b             -- the initial value of the accumulator
      -> [a]           -- the list to fold
      -> b             -- the result
```

It should be noted that although the `foldr` function accepts only three arguments we are applying it two four arguments:

```hs
foldr step id xs z
```

However, as you can see the second argument to `foldr` (i.e. the inital value of the accumulator) is `id` which is a function of the type `x -> x`. Therefore, the result is also of the type `x -> x`. Hence, it accepts four arguments.

Similarly, the step function is now of the type `a -> (x -> x) -> x -> x`. Hence, it accepts three arguments instead of two. The accumulator is an [endofunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endomorphism#Endofunctions) (i.e. a function whose domain and codomain is the same).

Endofunctions have a special property, they are composed from left to right instead of from right to left. For example, let's compose a bunch of `Int -> Int` functions:

```hs
inc :: Int -> Int
inc n = n + 1

dbl :: Int -> Int
dbl n = n * 2
```

The normal way to compose these functions is to use the function composition operator as follows:

```hs
incDbl :: Int -> Int
incDbl = inc . dbl
```

The `incDbl` function first doubles a number and then increments it. Note that this reads from right to left.

Another way to compose them is to use continuations (denoted by `k`):

```hs
inc' :: (Int -> Int) -> Int -> Int
inc' k n = k (n + 1)

dbl' :: (Int -> Int) -> Int -> Int
dbl' k n = k (n * 2)
```

Notice that the first argument is a continuation. If we want to recover the original functions then we can do:

```hs
inc :: Int -> Int
inc = inc' id

dbl :: Int -> Int
dbl = dbl' id
```

However, if we want to compose them then we do it as follows:

```hs
incDbl' :: (Int -> Int) -> Int -> Int
incDbl' = dbl' . inc'

incDbl :: Int -> Int
incDbl = incDbl' id
```

Notice that although we are still using the dot operator to compose the functions, it now reads from left to right.

This is the key behind making `foldr` behave as `foldl`. We fold the list from right to left but instead of folding it into a value, we fold it into an endofunction which when applied to an initial accumulator value actually folds the list from left to right.

Consider our `incDbl` function:

```hs
incDbl = incDbl' id
       = (dbl' . inc') id
       =  dbl' (inc' id)
```

Now consider the definition of `foldr`:

```hs
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
foldr _   acc []     = acc
foldr fun acc (y:ys) = fun y (foldr fun acc ys)
```

In the basis case we simply return the accumulated value. However, in the inductive case we return `fun y (foldr fun acc ys)`. Our `step` function is defined as follows:

```hs
step :: a -> (x -> x) -> x -> x
step x g a = g (f a x)
```

Here `f` is the reducer function of `foldl` and is of the type `x -> a -> x`. Notice that `step x` is an endofunction of the type `(x -> x) -> x -> x` which we know can be composed left to right.

Hence the folding operation (i.e. `foldr step id`) on a list `[y1,y2..yn]` looks like:

```hs
step y1 (step y2 (... (step yn id)))

-- or

(step y1 . step y2 . {dots} . step yn) id
```

Each `step yx` is an endofunction. Hence, this is equivalent to composing the endofunctions from left to right.

When this result is applied to an initial accumulator value then the list folds from left to right. Hence, `myFoldl f z xs = foldr step id xs z`.

---

Now consider the `foldl` function (which is written in Standard ML and not OCaml). It is defined as:

```ml
fun foldl f e l = let fun g (x, f'') = fn y => f'' (f (x, y))
                  in  foldr g (fn x => x) l e end
```

The biggest difference between the `foldr` functions of Haskell and SML are:

1. In Haskell the reducer function has the type `a -> b -> b`.
2. In SML the reducer function has the type `(a, b) -> b`.

Both are correct. It's only a matter of preference. In SML instead of passing two separate arguments, you pass one single tuple which contains both arguments.

Now, the similarities:

1. The `id` function in Haskell is the anonymous `fn x => x` function in SML.
2. The `step` function in Haskell is the function `g` in SML which takes a tuple containing the first two arguments.
3. The `step` function is Haskell `step x g a` has been split into two functions in SML `g (x, f'') = fn y => f'' (f (x, y))` for more clarity.

If we rewrite the SML function to use the same names as in Haskell then we have:

```ml
fun myFoldl f z xs = let step (x, g) = fn a => g (f (a, x))
                     in foldr step (fn x => x) xs z end
```

Hence, they are exactly the same function. The expression `g (x, f'')` simply applies the function `g` to the tuple `(x, f'')`. Here `f''` is a valid identifier.

Answer (score 4):

## Intuition

The foldl function traverses the list head to tail while operating elements with an accumulator:

(...(a⊗x<sub>1</sub>)⊗...⊗x<sub>n-1</sub>)⊗x<sub>n</sub>

And you want to define it via a foldr:

x<sub>1</sub>⊕(x<sub>2</sub>⊕...⊕(x<sub>n</sub>⊕e)...)

Rather unintuitive. The trick is that your foldr will not produce a value, but rather a function. The list traversal will operate the elements as to produce a function that, when applied to the accumulator, performs the computation you desire.

Lets see a simple example to illustrate how this works. Consider `sum foldl (+) 0 [1,2,3] = ((0+1)+2)+3`. We may calculate it via foldr as follows.

```
   foldr ⊕ [1,2,3] id 
-> 1⊕(2⊕(3⊕id))
-> 1⊕(2⊕(id.(+3))
-> 1⊕(id.(+3).(+2))
-> (id.(+3).(+2).(+1))
```

So when we apply this function to 0 we get

```
   (id.(+3).(+2).(+1)) 0
=  ((0+1)+2)+3
```

We began with the identity function and successively changed it as we traversed the list, using ⊕ where,

```
n ⊕ g = g . (+n)
```

Using this intuition, it isn't hard to define a sum with an accumulator via foldr. We built the computation for a given list via `foldr ⊕ id xs`. Then to calculate the sum we applied it to 0, `foldr ⊕ id xs 0`. So we have,

```
foldl (+) 0 xs = foldr ⊕ id xs 0 
               where n ⊕ g = g . (+n)
```

or equivalently, denoting `n ⊕ g` in prefix form by `(⊕) n g` and noting that `(⊕) n g a = (g . (+n)) a = g (a+n)`,

```
foldl (+) 0 xs = foldr ⊕ id xs 0
               where (⊕) n g a = g (a+n)
```

Note that the ⊕ is your step function, and that you can obtain the generic result you're looking for by substituting a function f for +, and accumulator a for 0.

Next let us show that the above really is correct.

## Formal derivation

Moving on to a more formal approach. It is useful, for simplicity, to be aware of the following universal property of foldr.

```
h []     = e
h (x:xs) = f x (h xs)

      iff 

h = foldr f e
```

This means that rather than defining foldr directly, we may instead and more simply define a function h in the form above.

We want to define such an h so that,

```
h xs a = foldl f a xs
```

or equivalently,

```
h xs = \a -> foldl f a xs
```

So lets determine h. The empty case is simple:

```
h [] = \a -> foldl f a []
     = \a -> a
     = id
```

The non-empty case results in:

```
h (x:xs) = \a -> foldl f a (x:xs)
         = \a -> foldl f (f a x) xs
         = \a -> h xs (f a x)
         = step x (h xs)   where step x g = \a -> g (f a x) 
         = step x (h xs)   where step x g a = g (f a x)
```

So we conclude that,

```
h []     = id
h (x:xs) = step x (h xs) where step x g a = g (f a x)
```

satisfies `h xs a = foldl f a xs`

And by the universal property above (noting that the f in the universal property formula corresponds to step here, and e to id) we know that `h = foldr step id`. Therefore,

```
h      = foldr step id
h xs a = foldl f a xs
-----------------------
foldl f a xs = foldr step id xs a  
             where step x g a = g (f a x)
```